# Disable button after reRender

Tags: visualforce

I have a button on the visual force page and I want to disable it for 3 minutes and enable it again after 3 minutes. I can not do this because of reRender parameter. How can I do that?

```
<apex:commandButton id="wmsBtn" action="{!sendToWMS}" value="{!$Label.Send_To_WMS}"  rendered="{!IF(((selectedOrderType != 'Sales Order' && selectedStatus =='Approved') || (selectedOrderType == 'Sales Order' && selectedStatus =='Allocated')),true,false)}" status="pageStatus" reRender="filterForm"/>
```

Comment: Sounds like this may be an XY problem. What is the overall goal here?

Comment: And in general, you'd need to store/fetch the time this button needs to be disabled in an SObject record and use Javascript to manage the disabling/re-enabling if you want to have the disablement behavior be able to handle stuff like whole-page refreshes. Possible to do, but somewhat painful to implement. If there's another approach you can use to achieve the overall goal behind this question, you should really consider avoiding this "long disable" approach.

Comment: @DerekF Sorry for the late reply. This button sends a request to a service. However, sometimes the service may take time to perform the previous operation and the second request may time out. They want the button to be disabled until the process is finished on the server.